# Multyply row by row in pandas using groupby apply function

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I would like calculate value for price in year 2024,2025,2026

I have that table

```
import investpy
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
years = [2023,2024,2025,2026]
cena_dict = {
    "Product" : ["Apple","Orange","Apple","Orange","Apple","Orange","Apple","Orange"],
    "Price" : [1,2,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN],
    "Rok" : [ 2023,2023,2024,2024,2025,2025,2026,2026],
    "CPI" : [10.4, 10.4 ,9 ,9 , 8.6 ,8.6 ,5.4 ,5.4]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(cena_dict)
print(df)
```

I can calculate value for year 2024, 2025 and 2026 in case when in column "Product" is unique value: I used that code below:

```
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    df[i, 'Price'] = df[i-1, 'Price'] * (1 + df[i, 'CPI'] / 100)
```

I would like to groupby df by ["Rok","Product"] and use apply function
but I can't use thats loop in group by function

thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Let us use some maths along with custom transformation function

```
def func(g):
    cpi = g['CPI'].iloc[1:]
    return (1 + cpi / 100).cumprod() * g['Price'].iat[0]

price = df.groupby('Product', group_keys=False).apply(func)
df['Price'].update(price)
```

---

```
  Product     Price   Rok   CPI
0   Apple  1.000000  2023  10.4
1  Orange  2.000000  2023  10.4
2   Apple  1.090000  2024   9.0
3  Orange  2.180000  2024   9.0
4   Apple  1.183740  2025   8.6
5  Orange  2.367480  2025   8.6
6   Apple  1.247662  2026   5.4
7  Orange  2.495324  2026   5.4
```